# Why my component is rendering 6 times, two for each data change?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to get a data from an API in the first rendering of the component, but I don't exactly know why the component is rendering 6 times, two times for each data change. Shouldn't the useEffect execute once?

**App.js:**

```
import './App.css'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function App() {

  const [words, setWords] = useState()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const requestRandomStringFromAPI = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
      const { fact } = await response.json()
      const threeFirstWords = fact.split(' ', 3).join(' ')
      setWords(threeFirstWords)
    }

    requestRandomStringFromAPI()
  }, [])

  console.log(words)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{words}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the average output on console:

```
App.js:19 undefined
App.js:19 undefined
App.js:19 The longest living
App.js:19 The longest living
App.js:19 Statistics indicate that
App.js:19 Statistics indicate that
```

Comment: A component will re-render whenever its state change. For the double rendering my guess is that you have Strict Mode enabled?

Comment: Yes, strict mode was enabled, I disabled it, and now the component just render two times. I suppose I can consider it as a solution?

Comment: You should use strict mode during development. It should be disabled once in production, but it is a great way to catch side effects.

Comment: CodeoftheWarrior, so why when I have strict mode, the useEffect executes twice? I keep getting one response from the API, but instantly I get another one. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think wrapping your app `<React.StrictMode>` causing this. [Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and React Developer Tools extension can render your component multiple times for debugging. This won't happen in a production build.